Convergence radius of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} e^n z^{n!}$
Exercise. Find the convergence radius of $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n!}$$ Then, use an analogue argument to find the radius of $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} e^n z^{n!}$$

For the first series, I've found that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n!}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}a_mz^m$$ where $$a_m=\begin{cases}1, & m=n!, \hspace{3pt} m\geq 2\\ 0, & m\ne n! \\ 2, & m=0,1\end{cases}$$
So, $$\limsup_m \sqrt[m]{|a_m|}=\inf_n \sup_{m\geq n}\{|a_m|^{1/m}\}=1$$ and applying the root criterion, the convergence radius is $\rho=1$.

Using the same idea, for the second series I've found that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n!}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}a_mz^m$$ where $$a_m=\begin{cases}e^n, & m=n!, \hspace{3pt} m\geq 2\\ 0, & m\ne n! \\ 1+e, & m=0,1\end{cases}$$
So, $$\limsup_m \sqrt[m]{|a_m|}=\inf_n \sup_{m\geq n}\{e^{n/m}\}=\inf_n \lim_n e^{n/n!}=1$$ and applying the root criterion, the convergence radius is $\rho=1$.
Is it a correct adaptation of the previous idea? (If it is right)

Both are correct. The first one is a megaduplicate: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7Dz%5E%7Bn!%7D%24&p=1

Thank you. I'm sorry for the duplicate, I didn't see it!

This question is similar to: Find radius convergence of power series.

@AnneBauval Sorry for this off-topic comment, but how did you make it so approach0 only returns hits from MSE?

@MikeEarnest: See “2. Limit data source to MSE:” in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969.

@MikeEarnest I copied-pasted AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com from a query by another user.
